# Why does this DFS code only work calling it within a generator?

Tags: python, generator, depth-first-search

I would really appreciate your assistance. I am studying DFS paths and I understand the code but what I do not understand is the last line. Why can't I just call the function as dfs_paths(graph, 'A', 'F') and not list(dfs_paths(graph, 'A', 'F')) for the code below to work? Thank you.

```
graph = {'A': set(['B', 'C']),
         'B': set(['A', 'D', 'E']),
         'C': set(['A', 'F']),
         'D': set(['B']),
         'E': set(['B', 'F']),
         'F': set(['C', 'E'])}

def dfs_paths(graph, start, goal):
    stack = [(start, [start])]
    while stack:
        (vertex, path) = stack.pop()
        for next in graph[vertex] - set(path):
            if next == goal:
                yield path + [next]
            else:
                stack.append((next, path + [next]))

dfs_paths(graph, 'A', 'F')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `dfs_paths` isn't a regular function; it's a generator function. When you run the function, it only returns a generator, and doesn't actually execute any of the code in the body until you start to iterate over the return value. That iteration can be explicit via a `for` loop:

```
for path in dfs_paths(graph, 'A', 'F'):
    ...
```

or implicit via a function like `list` that consumes an iterator:

```
paths = list(dfs_paths(graph, 'A', 'F'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the yield statement in the function.

Methods with a yield in them are generators. Generators return an iterator when invoked. If you want to get the full return value (the whole path) you have to finish iteration over the iterator. Hence the need for the `list()` - that implicitly iterates over the iterator giving you the whole path.